# HtmlEncode & HtmlDecode in WCF OData service

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, html-encode

I have an OData service that exposes my entities to a Javascript management UX.
For security reasons, I need to HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode any string values that pass through the service. (Encoding must happen server-side, and not in JS)

I'm encoding strings in a ChangeInterceptor; that works beautifully.
How can I HtmlDecode values on the way out? QueryInterceptors aren't designed to do this sort of thing, and I don't want to leave it to the client to re-construct these values.

If it's not possible in the OData layer, can I implement the encode/decode process in the underlying EntityFramework context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well the underlying EF context would handle the encoding/decoding process for you, but I can say that we are currently in the midst of adding some events that fire extremely late in the request process and should give you the ability to handle this scenario. You can expect those events sometime this calendar year (2012), most likely in 5.1.0 or 5.2.0.